# How to delete old emails from Google Analytics account

Tags: email, google-analytics

To get the weekly report of the visitors on my website, I added an email account into the report section of the Google Analytics. Now, I want to remove that old email and want to add the new email, but I didn't find the way to delete the old email address. Please help me!

Below are the steps:

1. First I clicked the **Behavior** section on the Left sidebar.
2. Then I clicked the **SITE CONTENT** section under Behavior.
3. Under Site Content I clicked **All Pages**.

Below is the screenshot (After Click all Pages)
[image]

- After that I clicked the **EMAIL** tab

Below is the screenshot of the dialog box that popped up

[image]

Then I click over the **ADD TO AN EXISTING EMAIL**

Another dialog box pooped up
[image]

Here is my old email address and I want to delete it, but don't know how.
Thanks!

Comment: So basically you want to transfer google analytics from one account to another?

Comment: No, not transfer. I just want to delete that email from weekly report. It's my person account and I want to remove that account because I have to add company's email address.

Comment: First you will have to add a new email, then delete the previous one. Did you find a way to add new email?

Comment: To delete old email. Click user manager tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GO TO ADMIN SECTION OF YOUR **GOOGLE ANALYTICS ACCOUNT**

[image]

After clicking **Admin** from top menu bar, you will see the something similar. *(Look over the picture)*

Under View Section, click over the **Scheduled emails**. (Another page will open up - **Look Below**)
[image]

This page will have all of your Scheduled Emails, then select the email that you want to delete and click over the Action Button, it will show the delete button and then you will be able to delete it